# pyqt how to get python timestamp from QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a QDateTimeEdit in my QT UI.

I have seen that I can achieve a python timestamp from a QDateTime using:

```
my_time = QDateTime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
my_time = my_time.toPyDateTime()
```

My question is: how can I create a QDateTime object from my QDateTimeEdit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

Given you have your QDateTimeEdit as variable self.my_tedit you can achieve the result in this way

```
my_time = my_tedit.dateTime()
my_time = my_time.toPyDateTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Qt have renamed the function. .toPyDatetime didn't work. This did work: `.toPython()`

```
my_time = my_tedit.dateTime()
my_time = my_time.toPython()
```